# Get groupId from a hook in Lifeway

Tags: java, liferay, hook, liferay-6

I'm looking for a was to get the groupId. To be more specific, I want to get the site ID of a community or organisation when a user signs in so I can redirect the user to the right "site".

I tried looking into PortalUtil in Liferay's documentation but it doesn't offer an easy function to get that ID.

I also tried ThemeDisplay but that only works for portlets.

Comment: Instead of saying I tried, please show us what you tried by putting your code in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an excerpt from a `LoginPostAction` in `hook` which serves your needs.

```
User user = PortalUtil.getUser(request);
List<Organization> orgList = OrganizationLocalServiceUtil.getUserOrganizations(user.getUserId());
for (Organization org : orgList) { 
 String orgFriendlyURL = org.getGroup().getFriendlyURL();
.
.//some custom code
.
String myPath = "/" + language + "/group" + orgFriendlyURL + "/home";
LastPath lastPath = new LastPath(StringPool.BLANK, myPath);
HttpSession session = request.getSession();
session.setAttribute(WebKeys.LAST_PATH, lastPath);
_log.debug("Last Path  for current User[" + user.getScreenName() + "] is : " + lastPath);
break;
}
```